# Set same position for multiple similar UV faces in UV Editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm learning the basics of UV mapping in Blender, and I can't find any way to snap all my UV faces to one position. I tried to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Snap selected to cursor*, but it ends up snapping every vertex to one point. I'm using Blender 2.82.

[image: my project]